# why shell script with hadoop wont work?

Tags: hadoop, sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo textFile :"$1"
echo mapper : "$2"
echo reducer: "$3"
echo inputDir :"$4"
echo outputDir: "$5"

hdfs dfs -ls ~

hdfs dfs -rm ~/"$2"
hdfs dfs -rm ~/"$3"



hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "$2" ~ # copies mapper.py file from argument to hdfs dir   
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "$3" ~ # copies reducer.py file from argument to hdfs dir


hdfs dfs -test -d ~/"$5"  #checks to see if hadoop output dir exists
if [ $? == '0' ]; then
    hdfs dfs -rm -r ~/"$5"
else
    echo "Output file doesn't exist and will be created when hadoop runs"
fi



hdfs dfs -test -d ~/"$4" #checks to see if hadoop input dir exists
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    hdfs dfs -rm -r ~/"$4"
    echo "Hadoop input dir alread exists deleting it now and creating a new      one..."
    hdfs dfs -mkdir ~/"$4"  # makes an input dir for text file to be put in

else
    echo "Input file doesn't exist will be created now"
    hdfs dfs -mkdir ~/"$4"  # makes an input dir for text file to be put in
fi



hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/"$1" ~/"$4" # sends textfile from local   to hdfs folder

# runs the hadoop mapreduce program with given parameters
  hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.2.jar \
-input /home/hduser/"$4"/* \
-output /home/hduser/"$5" \
-file /home/hduser/"$2" \
-mapper /home/hduser/"$2" \
-file /home/hduser/"$3" \
-reducer /home/hduser/"$3"
```

i wanted to avoid keep tying all the commands to run simple mapreduce everytime i want to test out mapper and reducer files so i wrote this script and i am new to shell scripting. I attached the screens

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two obvious details you should correct:

1. the operator for equals in bash spells '"' not '=='
   (actualle this is true for test expressions)
2. your long comman line for the hadoop call is spread accross several lines
   you need to concatenate these to a single (long) line or better indicate 
   continuation by ending the line using a backslash "\".

Comment: i edited it with ur suggestions, does it looks right? now

Comment: The "==" still are in. (They are causing the unexpected operator error messages).